# Nativescript 7 App unexpectedly crashes in ios == Assertion failed ==

Tags: javascript, ios, crash, nativescript, v8

I am developing an app using Nativescript 7 and it keeps crashing unexpectedly in iOS. All versions of iOS crash (12, 13, and 14 so far).

Here is the stack trace:

```
====== Assertion failed ======
Native stack trace:
1          0x10ac972af tns::Assert(bool, v8::Isolate*) + 119
2          0x10abf8259 tns::ArgConverter::Invoke(v8::Local<v8::Context>, objc_class*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, tns::V8Args&, tns::MethodMeta const*, bool) + 95
3          0x10ac58e5a tns::MetadataBuilder::InvokeMethod(v8::Local<v8::Context>, tns::MethodMeta const*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, tns::V8Args&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool) + 76
4          0x10ac58773 tns::MetadataBuilder::MethodCallback(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) + 219
5          0x10ade413c v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(v8::internal::CallHandlerInfo) + 620
6          0x10ade35ec v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<false>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) + 556
7          0x10ade2c73 v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) + 259
8          0x10b67bc19 Builtins_CEntry_Return1_DontSaveFPRegs_ArgvOnStack_BuiltinExit + 57
JavaScript stack trace:
at requestLayout (file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/index.ios.js:37:0)
at <anonymous> (file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/properties/index.js:895:0)
at <anonymous> (file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/properties/index.js:902:0)
at eachChildView (file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/content-view/index.js:65:0)
at eachChild (file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-common.js:700:0)
at <anonymous> (file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/properties/index.js:897:0)
at clearInheritedProperties (file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/properties/index.js:1144:0)
at _parentChanged (file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:683:36)
at _removeView (file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:463:0)
at _removeContainer (file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/list-view/index.ios.js:411:0)
```

`nativescript.config.ts`

```js
import { NativeScriptConfig } from '@nativescript/core';

export default {
  id: 'org.nativescript.sampleapp',
  appResourcesPath: 'App_Resources',
  android: {
    v8Flags: '--expose_gc',
    markingMode: 'none',
    discardUncaughtJsExceptions: true
  },
  ios: {
    discardUncaughtJsExceptions: true
  }
} as NativeScriptConfig;
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "@nativescript/template-hello-world",
  "main": "app.js",
  "version": "7.0.1",
  "author": "NativeScript Team <oss@nativescript.org>",
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "nstudio",
    "nativescript",
    "mobile",
    "{N}",
    "tns",
    "template"
  ],
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-app-templates",
  "dependencies": {
    "@nativescript/camera": "^5.0.2",
    "@nativescript/core": "~7.0.13",
    "@nativescript/imagepicker": "^1.0.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "^2.3.3",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-cardview": "^2.0.1",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-pulltorefresh": "^3.0.1",
    "nativescript": "^7.0.12",
    "nativescript-barcodescanner": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nativescript/android": "7.0.1",
    "@nativescript/ios": "7.0.6",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~3.0.8"
  },
  "gitHead": "xyz",
  "private": "true",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

I am suspecting that the version of Nativescript is the reason behind this and if an update is available, the bug might have been fixed in v8.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is it worth trying to do:

> tns update next

Comment: Updated nativescript version. Further, updated `@nativescript/core`, `@nativescript/android`, and `@nativescript/ios`. Unfortunately, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a github issue for the v8 runtime for Nativescript mentioning the exact same issue. In order to follow it only in one place, please see [the link](https://github.com/NativeScript/ns-v8ios-runtime/issues/61).

It mentions the following:

- When navigating back from a RadListView or a ScrollView, the application might unexpectedly crash because of a bug in ios's v8 engine.
- Some people mentioned that they only faced this issue when the orientation of the list or scroll view is horizontal.
- The team is still working towards making the application at least not crash when this problem occurs.